# Set background color on listviewrow

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview, listviewitem

I have been trying to set a background color of the ListViewRow depending on if the checkbox is selected.

Here is the code i have so far and I'm stuck.

```
For Each lvi As ListViewItem In lvwQuotes.Items
    Dim sssss = lvi.FindControl("chk_firstitem")
    If DirectCast(sssss, System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox).Checked = True Then
        'WHAT DO
    End If
Next
```

Here is the ASP.NET code i have for the checkbox.

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chk_firstitem"></asp:CheckBox>
```

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: try this...  lvi.BackColor = System.Drawing.Blue

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help. I have found a similar link on 'msdn.microsoft.com'

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750769%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Is this just for alternative rows as if it is i just want a row background on the selected row.

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each lvi As ListViewItem In lvwQuotes.Items
    Dim sssss = lvi.FindControl("chk_firstitem")
    If DirectCast(sssss, System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox).Checked = True Then
         lvi.BackColor = System.Drawing.Blue 
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I get an error that 'BackColor' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItem'

Comment: Acording to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx it is... what error do you get?